# Enable AP mode on router (ZTE MF60)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I wanted to use the ZTE MF60 router I own as an access point to extend my current 4G router. According to [this](https://bc.whirlpool.net.au/bc/hardware/?action=h_view&model_id=1262), the device should be able to do so. However I haven't managed to enable the AP mode or configure the router using the my current [firmware](https://sites.google.com/site/mf60guide/). How do I go about, any suggestions?

The following is the configuration I have for my device
[image: Network]
[image: Security]
[image: LAN]

I used the same SSID and password on both routers, however changed the channel frequency on my 4G router to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extend your 4G router with this one, it would need to support repeater mode which is told on your page that is not supported.

In mobile hotspots, Access Point is referred as a [APN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_Point_Name) (Access Point Name) of your cell carrier so the connection comes from the cell network rather than a router.

The [manual](https://data2.manualslib.com/pdf3/70/6921/692081-zte/mf60.pdf?c1555222c51d1d65970f3889948b8ee6) doesn't mention any repeater mode nor a way to extend a existing network.

Comment: https://bc.whirlpool.net.au/bc/hardware/?action=h_view&model_id=1262 This had me confused, in that the wifi section says its supports AP mode but not repeater

Comment: @NSCoder it's a access point from a GPRS/UTMS connection.